# What are the prices of coffee in Poland compared to USA

Tags: usa, budget, poland, food-and-drink

I live in USA but I'm traveling to Poland for the summer. I am wondering what are the prices in USD of coffee in Poland.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In big Polish cities be prepared to pay around 10 PLN, which is about $3, in Starbucks and similar for a black coffee. In McDonalds you will pay around half of it. It goes down to around $1 in smaller cafeterias outside of the city center. But as usually, it highly varies.

Comment: I heard it can get up to 15 PLN (almost $5) in the most touristy areas of Warsaw.

Comment: I bet you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Really cheap. It depends on the exact place you take it, but though it's not difficult to take a coffee for less than $.50 in a city center (I was at Poland last April). Of course, if you go to Starbucks, it will be more expensive, but in general it is cheaper than a Starbucks in USA.

Comment: what city center are you talking about?? Was it warsaw??

Comment: In general any city. Warsaw included, but that's true that the only coffee we take in warsaw (in a "milky bar", near central station) was a bit more expensive (3 PLN if I remember well).

Comment: $.50? are you sure? Being a Polish I have never seen coffee that cheap ... unless it was a coffee machine at university.

Comment: @Krizz you make me doubt.. :) but I've asked my travelmate and say literally: "I took a coffe in Poznan by 2 PLN" and can't remember any other price.

Comment: @Ivan Then, I may be overpaying :P or Poznan is cheaper than Wroclaw.

Comment: @Krizz Wroclaw was the most expensive city I've been in Poland :)

Comment: -1: sorry, it doesn't have much to do with reality. Lot of things are cheap in Poland, but coffee isn't one of them.

Comment: I live in Poland and can't recall any place with coffee for 0.5$ (1.50 PLN). Maybe somewhere there are, but for sure it's not true that you can easliy find coffee for 0.5$ in city centers.

Comment: Maybe it was a kiosk on the railway/bus station?

Answer (score 0):

Prices of coffee in Poland do vary greatly depending on the city and exact location and the retailer. You can easily buy a cup for about $0.50 at most coffee machines located at railway stations, shopping malls, etc. Also cheap bistros will sell you one for $0.7-1.20 and there are many like that in Poland, too. And if you look for something special you can easily find a nice local restaurant serving a cup of quality coffee for $2. I would say that $2.50-3.00 is the most you should pay. Anything more than that is just a rip-off in Poland and i would suggest to avoid such places.